# Drawing in cucumber or run an HTML request in step definitions

Tags: cucumber

I am pretty new to cucumber and using it to automate testing on our web application. One thing I am having issue with is a map we have on the app where we draw a "fenced" location on the map and set parameters for that location. I am not sure how I can draw the fence on the webpage with cucumber. Drawing on the web app is done by clicking the type of drawing you want to do (polygon, circle, etc) and then clicking and dragging on the map.  The other option would be to use our Jmeter HTML request in our step definitions. We used to run all our tests in Jmeter but are moving to cucumber.

Comment: maybe this helps http://vedanova.com/rails/cucumber/2012/11/30/cucumber-mouse-click-page-like-map.html

Comment: Cucumber is a test framework, which by itself does not interact with the web application. The web application interaction portion is done by another gem (library) such as Watir, Selenium, Capybara, etc. Specifying which gem you are using to interact with the web application and a sample of the html would improve the ability to answer your question.

Comment: We mostly use Watir-Webdriver but have each of the ones you mentioned.